# linux kernel character drivers

Tags: linux-kernel, driver

I have registered a character driver using the api `register_chrdrv()`.

The driver creates an entry in `/dev/myfile`.  User space applications can access my driver by opening the /dev/myfile. Now I want to make my character driver such that only one user space application can access my driver at a time; only when that user space application closes the file can another user space program access my driver.

Can this be done in the kernel level?

I don't have control of the number of applications running in user space so i have to make changes only in kernel level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the open method of your driver:
use a global flag to say whether the device is in use. Unset when closed (in the release method).
Pseudo-code:

```
am_open=False

open() method:
if (!am_open)
  am_open=True
  ...proceed...
else
  return -EAGAIN; // try again later
 -or-
  return -EBUSY;


release() method:
  am_open=False
```

Having said that, drivers (usually) should be a 100% reentrant :)

Comment: Thanks kaiwan rohit and user3387542

Comment: Thanks kaiwan rohit and user3387542 if i make my character driver reentrant which means multiple userspace application can access the driver at a time now how is it thread safe it is not thread safe am i correct or am i missing something . i would agree it is thread safe if the kernel internally handles the request one by one i mean just like queue

Comment: Hey @user3597661 if the answer is correct, pl mark it as such! :)

Reg your comment/qs: it is the driver author's responsibility to write reentrant safe code; this implies using mutexes (or spinlocks, whatever), where appropriate, perhaps using the 'file->private_data'  pointer as an kmalloc'ed location to hold per process state info, etc etc. 

If these details look new to you, pl read up on the topic- the (older) LDD Rubini book, the (newer) Essential Linux Device Drivers books should definitely help!

Comment: Thanks kaiwan your answer is correct how do i mark your answer correct i am new to this stackoverflow.com

Comment: Click the tick mark to the left of the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: thanks kaiwan for the help your solution is correct and it did work as well sorry for the delay in reply

Answer (score 0):

With a kernel char device you usually have the following methods.

```
.open
.read
.write
.release
```

(struct file_operations fops which will be used in the method register_chrdev(...,&fops).)

I would create your clients in a way that they open the device when they get started, and release it upon exiting. Like this you could easily handle / hinder a new (second) program of doing reads and writes on this device.

There may be other possibilities as well.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you want to synchronize your application so that at a time only one process can access it. You can go for `semaphore in kernel` or `locking methods in drivers` that may help you. You may refer this  http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/kernel/semaphore.c